# Angular 5 freezes UI when using ngx-pica Image resizer

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to create an image upload facility for my angular 5 site. It uses ngx-Pica to resize the images client side, but I am having issues with the UI freezing while the resize service is being called and I need some ideas on how to stop it freezing.

The image sizes are: (all added at the same time)

- 2.6mb
- 1.7mb
- 3.46mb

I don't understand what is causing the freeze any help would be appreciated.

**Things I have tried**

I've tried to remove `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` just to see if it stops the UI from freezing, it didn't

Adding the images without resizing them stops the freezing issue (removing the call to `this._ngxPicaService.resizeImage`)

I tried reviewing the source code but could't find anything that is glaringly obvious

I am providing the resizing functionality so I don't have to restrict the image size user uploads but obviously a frozen UI is not acceptable either

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

import { NgxPicaService, NgxPicaErrorInterface, NgxPicaResizeOptionsInterface, NgxPicaImageService } from 'ngx-pica';
import { AspectRatioOptions } from 'ngx-pica/src/ngx-pica-resize-options.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'az-multiple-image-uploader',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './multiple-image-uploader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multiple-image-uploader.component.scss']
})
export class MultipleImageUploaderComponent { 
    public images: File[] = [];

    constructor(
        private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, 
        private _ngxPicaService: NgxPicaService, 
        private _ngxPicaImageService: NgxPicaImageService 
    ) { }    

    fileChange(input){
        this.handleFiles(input.files);
    }

    private addLoadingAnimations(numberToAdd: number): void {
        var spinner = require("assets/img/Spinner.svg");

        for(var i =0; i < numberToAdd; i++)
        {
            this.images.push(spinner);
        }
    }

    public handleFiles(files: any) {
        var listLength = this.images.length;
        this.addLoadingAnimations(files.length);

        var width = 1024;
        var height = 683;

        for(var index = 0; index < files.length; index++){
            this._ngxPicaService.resizeImage(files[index], width, height, new ImageResizeOptions())
                .subscribe((imageResized: File) => {
                    let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

                    reader.addEventListener('load', (event: any) => {
                        this.images.splice(listLength, 1);
                        this.images[listLength] = event.target.result;
                        listLength += 1;
                        this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
                    }, false);

                    reader.readAsDataURL(imageResized);

            }, (err: NgxPicaErrorInterface) => {
                throw err.err;
            });
        }
    }

    removeImage(index):void{
        this.images.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

export class ImageResizeOptions implements NgxPicaResizeOptionsInterface
{
  aspectRatio = new ImageAspectRatioOptions(true);
}

export class ImageAspectRatioOptions implements AspectRatioOptions {
  keepAspectRatio: boolean;
  forceMinDimensions?: boolean;

  constructor(keepAspectRatio: boolean, forceMinDimensions?: boolean) {
    this.keepAspectRatio = keepAspectRatio;
    this.forceMinDimensions = forceMinDimensions;
  }
}


<div class="col-8 mx-auto">
    <input type="file" multiple (change)="fileChange(input)" #input class="m-img-upload-btn"/>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Images...
    </button>
</div>

<div class="card images-container">
    <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i=index;" class="m-image-wrapper">
        <i class="fa fa-times m-delete-img" (click)="removeImage(i)"></i>
        <img [src]="image"> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: While the accepted answer will solve your "freezing" issue, an arguably better solution would be to do the image resizing on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to stopping a UI from freezing is Web workers.

The task I was trying takes a long time and any long running computation will cause the ui to freeze.

In angular there is a nice little package called `https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-web-worker` which will help you implement web workers

Comment: Did web workers resolve the issue for you? If yes can you share your resize function that you input into web worker?